# Remotely access pc behind firewall from my dynamic-ip pc via a static-ip VPS

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, firewall, tunnel

I am not sure what is the term for what I want to do, and how secure it will be, but here is the setup:

I have full root access to `workpc` only physically when at work. It is behind a firewall which I do not control. I can not access `workpc` when at home from `homepc`.

I also have a VPS machine `vps`, out there somewhere, which has a static IP and I have full control over that too.

`homepc` does not have a static ip and also it is not on 24/7, unlike `vps` which is on 24/7 and has static ip.

Ideally, could I establish a long-term connection from `workpc` to `vps` when I am at work. And then when I go home, I connect `homepc` to `vps` and somehow access `workpc`?

I have full root access to all machines and all are running latest linux.

Comment: zerotier would be the easiest option, and does not require a VPS. A ssh reverse tunnel between your workpc and the VPS would also work.

Comment: Please make sure you're not creating [shadow IT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_IT). Any VPN will work. ZeroTier will require the least setup and you won't need the VPS at all.

Comment: To whom much is given (root access), much is expected (good infosec practices). Establishing a semi-permanent link to the outside world is risky.  I would be certain you understand the risks completely and address them. Even better-talk to your admins or infosec people before proceeding. They could have a solution at hand.

Comment: @uSlackr in the long term we are all powned but yes, thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mentioned what type of access do you want to have exactly, SSH, VNC, ... but there are several options.

1. Remote access software like TeamViewer or similar that you install on your `workpc` and can then access it from anywhere in the world with corresponding remote client. There is possibility this is against your company policies and blocked by network firewall.
2. VPN between your `workpc` and `vps`, you establish vpn connection from `workpc` to `vps`, and then you can connect from `homepc` to `vps` over vpn or ssh, and access `workpc` on its vpn address through `vps`. You would need to setup `vps` as vpn server running OpenVPN, WireGuard or some other type of VPN software.
3. SSH tunneling, you establish a ssh connection from `workpc` to `vps` with reverse tunneling, and then establish a ssh connection from your `homepc` to `vps` with forward tunneling, and you can then connect with ssh from your `homepc` to `workpc` through those two tunnels.

> example: `ssh -R 8022:localhost:22 user@vps`, this will establish a ssh connection from your `workpc` to `vps`, where you create a listener on port 8022 on `vps`, and every connection that comes to that port will be redirected through SSH to port 22 on your `workpc`.
>
> You then create another ssh connection from your `homepc` to `vps`, like `SSH -L 9022:localhost:8022 vps` which will create a listener locally on your `homepc` on port 9022, and every connection to that port will be send over SSH to port 8022 on `vps`, which will then enter the ssh tunnel with `workpc` and go to ssh server on `workpc`.
>
> You can then just do a ssh connection to localhost port 9022 and will be send to `workpc` port 22 to its ssh server. In this case `ssh user@localhost -p 9022` will be the same as doing `ssh user@workpc`
>
> You need to enable sshd service on your `workpc` in this case, as it needs to have ssh server running on it on port 22. In case you want to use some other port or service on your `workpc` to access, you replace port 22 in first reverse tunnel with the corresponding port you want to access on your `workpc`

Comment: Thank you @raiz, the purpose is plain command line access, as I would do if I could ssh. Your 2nd or 3rd suggestion is what I need, thank you.